# mysql date_format needs to return as string

Tags: mysql, string, date, vbscript

I have a small sql query that get the date part of a date time column

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(`tbldata`.`fldDate`, '%d/%m/%Y') AS formattedDate from tbldata
```

How can I convert this to a string?

I am running the sql query in a vbscript file and adding the returned data into an excel spreadsheet.

However, the script fails because the returned data is a date type.

Is there a way to ensure that the date returned from mysql is a string and not a date?

Thanks

Comment: Script fails becuse of strange `,"bb")` in your query.

Comment: Please post your real code. This won't even run.

Comment: I have amended the code, copy and paste error!

Answer (score 2):

The whole purpose of the [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function is to create a string. If you don't get a string back, you're doing something else (your SQL has syntax errors so you've probably stripped out something to post here).

**Edit:** Well, it's really weird that you're getting a date type given that `DATE_FORMAT()` allows any arbitrary output. I wonder what happens if you run e.g. this:

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(`tbldata`.`fldDate`, 'Hellow, World, today it is %m') AS formattedDate
from tbldata
```

Answer (score 0):

Dates *are* strings in MySQL. But if you really want to be sure use [`Cstr()`](http://support.technetex.ca/devguide/vbscript_functions.aspx):

Answer (score 0):

You can use CAST() function to achieve that, your SQL would be like this :

```
Select CAST( DATE_FORMAT(`tbldata`.`fldDate`, '%d/%m/%Y'),"bb") AS CHAR) AS formattedDate from tbldata
```

Here the reference of the CAST function : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

Have fun ! :)

Answer (score 0):

*>Is there a way to ensure that the date returned from mysql is a string and not a date?*

Yes, there is -

- Create a view with your query.
- Check column data types from `information_schema.columns` table.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM `information_schema`.`columns`
WHERE table_schema = 'database name' AND table_name = 'view name'
```